# HTC U Ultra: Can I use dual SIM on this device?

Tags: htc, dual-sim

There seem to exist different versions of the phone.

I can insert 2 nano SIM cards in the device but how to activate the second one? There is no enter PIN dialog popping up. On YouTube I saw an unboxing video that showed dual SIM support.

Comment: Use apps from play store like *device info / my device , etc*/ look at your purchase invoice which should have the model number to find out. Please do that first and ask.

Comment: In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjFFFEEO458) for example it says SIM2 on the adapter.

Comment: @MichaelS. Can you see two network  icons after inserting two sims on sim tray? I think you were doubted about 4G/3G settings on both sim.

Comment: @beeshyams: Could you provide a link to the app please?

Comment: @RahulGopi: If I insert the sim tray with 2 sims there is only the message that a sim (singular) has been inserted and the PIN shall be provided. There are no 2 icons like on my ZTE Axon were e.g.

Comment: [My device](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anu.main.myandroid). Google on Play store for *device* lots of other apps

Comment: Andy Yan's answer revealed that I have the single-SIM variant. Duh. This would have been nice to know in advance when buying the device. Anyone knows how to find out in store? It is not marked on the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter download mode by powering down the device and then holding both VOL_DOWN and POWER to power it back up. It will boot to a screen saying `hTC download mode`.

The 3rd line of the displayed info will say something like `htc_oceuhl PVT S-ON`. `uhl` corresponds to the single-SIM variant, `dugl` is the international dual-SIM variant, and `dtwl` is the Chinese dual-SIM variant.

You can exit the mode by selecting "reboot" in the download mode menu.

Comment: Any chance to find out in store before buying the next one?

Comment: Ask any store receptionist? You have the rights to know this info as a customer. What I offered is more of a surefire, after-purchase method and would help better in situations like buying a used device.